# VBA Creating list based on variables - insert different values predefined times

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I want to create column that will be filled by city names repeated "x" times.

Data taken from another sheet (Sheet1, column A (text), B (text) and F (formula)):

- London Q 3
- Paris R 2

Want to have (Sheet2, column A (text), B (text) and C (Number)):

- London Q 1
- London Q 2
- London Q 3
- Paris R 1
- Paris R 2

I know it is quite easy but I'm new in VBA :/
I've found code like below (from description it should do what I want), but - this loop never ends and xls crushes so I'm not able to see if it is doing what I want or not.

```
    Sub RunMe()
Dim CopyX, x As Integer
CopyX = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F1")
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Copy

Do
    x = x + 1
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Loop Until x = CopyX
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code 
 - loops through each item in sheet1
 - repeats the city name however many times are specified in col F
 - puts a 1 alongside the first entry
 - completes the series in successive cells in steps of 1 until the col F value is reached.

You may have to adjust sheet names.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For r = 1 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(.Cells(r, 6).Value).Value = .Cells(r, 1).Resize(, 2).Value
        ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = 1
        ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).DataSeries Step:=1, Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Stop:=.Cells(r, 6).Value
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works PERFECT! Is it possible to sort source data by F column values but not in source sheet? I mean is it possible to do it in a background to have in target sheet data sorted from the most numerous?

Comment: Yes it can be done, either by sorting in the output sheet (might need to add an extra column) or by putting data in an array and sorting that (plenty of examples online).

Comment: What's in the 9th row?

Comment: It was first ws2.Range... etc. row. But it was because of "0" values in my F/6th column :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything went great after inserting if statement because in data column F there also appears "0" values. Added also clearing and sorting. Maybe someone will use it so I implement whole code :)

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, ws2 As Worksheet
With Sheets("Sample_size")
Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("D2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
End With

Set ws2 = Sheets("Sample_size")

With Sheets("Pres")
    For r = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(r, 5).Value > 0 Then
        ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(.Cells(r, 5).Value).Value = .Cells(r, 1).Resize(, 2).Value
        ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(.Cells(r, 5).Value).Value = .Cells(r, 2).Resize(, 2).Value
        ws2.Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(.Cells(r, 5).Value).Value = .Cells(r, 5).Resize(, 2).Value
        ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = 1
        ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).DataSeries Step:=1, Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Stop:=.Cells(r, 5).Value

        End If
    Next r
End With

ws2.Range("A2:D2").End(xlDown).Sort _
Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
key2:=Range("c2"), order2:=xlAscending, _
key3:=Range("b2"), order3:=xlAscending


End Sub
```